# Running Theano on Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, theano

New to Theano when I tried to use the package I keep getting the following error:

ImportError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Dot22(, ), '\n', 'dlopen(/Userdir/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-14.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.11-64/tmpEBdQ_0/eb163660e6e45b373cd7909e14efd44a.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Userdir/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-14.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.11-64/tmpEBdQ_0/eb163660e6e45b373cd7909e14efd44a.so\n  Reason: image not found', '[Dot22(, )]')

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of theano and reinstall. If that doesn't work, reinstall all of python